# 4x4 square mapping to tick

Tags: grid-deduction

[image]

I cannot see any pattern in how the top left box maps to the top right box.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer (with ticks/checkmarks as Y and Xs as X) is

> YYXY 
>  YYXX 
>  YYYY 
>  YXYX

Because I’m on mobile, maybe this will work:

> ✅✅❌✅ 
>  ✅✅❌❌ 
>  ✅✅✅✅ 
>  ✅❌✅❌

This is because you need to

> Assign value of 1 to the first row and column, 2 to the second row and column, 3 to the third row and column, and 4 to the fourth row and column. Then the row and column totals represent the sum of the checkmarks for that row/column.